# TYPO3 9.5 show pdf file

Tags: typo3, media, typo3-9.x

My installation is TYPO3 9.5.4 plus bootstrap_package 10.0.4. I want to display a PDF file. I have included a content element type text & media to a page and connected with the PDF file. The backend shows the correct pre-view of the file. However, the frontend only shows the header line of the content element, not the PDF file (as picture). It worked under version 8.7.xx (at that time without bootstrap_package). Any hints how to solve this issue?

Comment: please provide some code of what you tried so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your installation has problems with reading PDF as image (please do the image checks). Anyway there are some PDF which can't be read because of their strange format.

As you have a backend preview image I assume the PDF is readable as image. And the preview image might exist since TYPO3 8. The FE rendering is done from current TYPO3 9 and maybe the graphic manipulation configuration is wrong.

Comment: I have executed the install-tool image check, and now discrepancies found. However, what i found is: in 8.7, backend, media adjustments, fields are shown for setting width/height of the element, while in 9.5 a blue colored error message is displayed, saying (under image manipulation) that no image dimensions could be determined (and  unable to provide image manipulation). I have tried with PDF files of different sizes and sources, but always the same result.

Comment: have you installed every component for reading PDFs as image? (ghostscript)

Comment: In meantime, I am pretty sure that the problem is coming from the extension bootstrap_package. I have installed a fresh Typo3 and included the PDF file as text&media, and it is displayed. When i install bootstrap_package, it is no more displayed. When i deactivate bootstrap_package, the PDF is displayed again. Perhaps i should open an issue on Github for bootstrap_package.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your both earlier comments. Image manipulation works with other file formats. I never installed Ghostscript before. In my Install Tool i can choose between Graphics Magick and Image Magick, but either selection shows same result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to expand the file:

```
typo3conf/ext/bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Partials/ContentElements/Media/Type.html
```

You need a new case for PDF files (Type 5):

```
<f:case value="5">
    <f:render partial="Media/Type/Image" arguments="{file: file, data: data, settings: settings, variants: variants}" />
</f:case>
```

You can copy the file in your sitepackage and expand